# Enabling X-Spam-Report in SpamAssassin

Tags: spamassassin, spam-filter

I tried to enable header `X-Spam-Report` in `local.cf`:

```
report_safe 0
```

Per [instructions](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html) this should cause adding this header to emails. Yet the header is not there.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you also set `remove_header` and `clear_headers` appropriately?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have not set either.